# How create new layout with js and css in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new in ROR and I am using Rails 5 version.

I want to use different different layout for different different controller.
I am using Devise if Devise call with sing_in and sign_up action then call devise layout with only devise.js and devise.css. So How to call and generate devise layout with js and css.

Another one
How to create new layout Like dashboard.html.erb with dashboard.js and dashboard.css and how to call. and If dashboard will call then only dashboard.js and dashboard.css call.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

in your app/layouts/ 
add the file

```
devise.html.erb
```

In that file you can call only the js and css files you need. And so on....In your controller you can determine layout by

```
layout 'example'
```